# React Jest Enzyme - test failed when import markdown

Tags: reactjs, markdown, jestjs, enzyme

When I try to run my test they failed in my class he's trying to import my markdown files:

```
import StartRecord from './Documentation/content/API/Start_record.md';
import UseLive from './Documentation/content/User/Live.md';
import UseRecord from './Documentation/content/User/Record.md';
import UseReplay from './Documentation/content/User/Replay.md';
import Settings from './Documentation/content/User/Settings.md';
```

Here is my failed message:

```
FAIL  src/__test__/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

/Users/anyone/Desktop/web/src/Modules/Dashboard/Documentation/content/User/Live.md:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){# Interface
                                                                                         ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

   8 | // Content
   9 | import StartRecord from './Documentation/content/API/Start_record.md';
> 10 | import UseLive from './Documentation/content/User/Live.md';
     | ^
  11 | import UseRecord from './Documentation/content/User/Record.md';
  12 | import UseReplay from './Documentation/content/User/Replay.md';
  13 | import Settings from './Documentation/content/User/Settings.md';
```

I have search many error like but never found with markdown.

I use webpack and have already configure it to read markdown. (It's a part of the webconfig file)

```
{
        test: /\.md$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        use: [
            {
                loader: "html-loader"
            },
            {
                loader: "markdown-loader"
            }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: You have Webpack setup but Jest don't know anything about it. The MD files are relevant for your tests? You might want to mock them. There is a dedicated section about Jest + Webpack in the doc. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack

Comment: Thanks, I have to get them to test if my test render the correct text (same as each md)

Comment: You can test that in the different paths of your code you actually render the correct file with a mock. The content of the file itself doesn't matter much. You can test the content outside of a unit test e.g integration test.

Comment: Yes but many of my component are bound together and per example my Dashboard need to test render with Documentation so it fail all the test for it and I need to import them anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution in my jest config by adding to extensions and moduleNameMapper the `html` and `md` like that:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'json', 'png', 'md', 'html'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)?$': 'babel-jest'
  },
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga|md|html)$": "<rootDir>/assetsTransformer.js",
    "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/assetsTransformer.js"
  },
  "setupFiles": [
    "./configJSDom.js"
  ],
  "collectCoverage": true,
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "src/*.js",
    "src/*/*.js",
    "src/*/*/*.js",
    "!src/test.js",
    "!src/serviceWorker.js",
    "!src/index.js"
  ]
};
```